# Initial value problem with initial curves

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Please help me solve the following:

Consider the initial value problem:
$$\ xy\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + (2y^2 - x^6)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0 ; x>0,y\geq0 \\ u(x(t),y(t)) = t^2$$

and the initial curves:

$$\ l_1\ : (x(t),y(t)) = (t,\alpha t) \\
l_2 : (x(t),y(t)) = (t,\alpha t^2) \\
l_3 : (x(t),y(t)) = (t,\alpha t^3) \\
\alpha \geq 0
$$

a) Calculate the characteristic base curves (Hint:
take $y^2$ as the new variable).

b) Investigate for all initial curves if the initial value problem can
be solved. If this is the case, give the solution.

c) Investigate for all problems where the solution is unique.

Thnx in advance!

Comment: @robert-israel I don't know where the initial curves come into play. I thought about starting with using the Lagrange-Charpit equation to solve the problem, but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on exactly this problem as well and have not been able to solve it completely so far. This is as far as I got.

$$
\frac{d u}{d s} = \frac{d x}{d s} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{d y}{d s} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
$$

So,

$$
\frac{d u}{d s} = 0
$$

and,

$$
\frac{d x}{d s} = xy
$$
$$
\frac{d y}{d s} = 2y^2 - x^6
$$

combining gives,

$$
d s = \frac{d x}{xy} = \frac{d y}{2y^2 - x^6}
$$

$$
\frac{d y}{d x} = \frac{2y^2 - x^6}{xy} = \frac{2y}{x} - \frac{x^5}{y}
$$

using the substitution $v = y^2$ one can solve this ODE and will get,

$$
y = \pm x^2 \sqrt{c - x^2}
$$

or by rewriting,

$$
c = \frac{y^2 + x^6}{x^4} = constant
$$

Therefore one can choose $\Phi = \frac{y^2 + x^6}{x^4}$ since $d \Phi = 0$ and 'obviously' we can take $\Psi = 0$ (I do not really understand why, but it has to do with $\frac{d u}{d s} = 0$ i reckon, see the link below).

Now the general solution becomes,

$$
F(\Phi,\Psi) = F(\frac{y^2 + x^6}{x^4},u) = 0
$$

or,

$$
u(x,y) = F(\frac{y^2 + x^6}{x^4})
$$

(see, https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/436.A1.12f/PDE_Meth_Characteristics.pdf'>this link)

Comment: I had done somthing similar, but I don't see where the initial curves come into play, so I thought maybe i was on the wrong track.
I still don't know what to do next.

Comment: Now plugging in the first initial condition ($x = t, y=\alpha t, u = t^2$) gives you $F(t^2 + \alpha^2/t^2) = t^2$.  Putting $s = t^2 + \alpha^2/t^2$ and solving for $t^2$ you get $F(s) = (s \pm \sqrt{s^2-4\alpha^2})/2$.  Similarly for the other initial curves.

Comment: Of course you'll have to worry about the quantity inside the square root becoming negative...